# String index out of Bounds Exception error

Tags: java, exception, indexing

I am making a program to read .java files and extract all comments from it and write it to an html file. The file works mostly but i am having trouble extracting the names of each method as it confuses "Exception{" as a separate class/method.

So far this is the code i have and i believe it is almost done.

http://pastebin.com/qrbJAaW3

```
    public class ParseDoc {

            static String fileName = null;
            static String outputR = "";
            static String inputR = "";
            static String[] lines;
            static String [] classnames;
            static StringBuilder classn = new StringBuilder();
            static String classnam = "";
            /**
             * This Method asks the user for path to input and output file
             * then it reads the file and places it on a string for easier sorting.
             * The string is sorted line by line into an array and cleaned.
             * @return Array of DOC comments
             * @throws Exception
             */
            public static String[] scanread() throws Exception{

                    System.out.println("NOTICE: If a valid file path is not entered, the program will not return a DOCHTML document.");
                    Scanner inputReader = new Scanner(System.in);
                    System.out.println("Please enter path to input file (ex: C:/Program Files/Code.java : " );
                    inputR = inputReader.nextLine();

                    System.out.println("Please enter path to html output file (ex: C:/Program Files/Output.html : " );
                    outputR = inputReader.nextLine();
                    inputReader.close();


                            FileReader file = new FileReader(inputR);
                            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file);
                            String line = reader.readLine();
                            //NAME OF THE SOURCE FILE
                            int index = inputR.lastIndexOf("/");
                            fileName = inputR.substring(index + 1);



                            int z = 0;
                            //This loop turns the input file into an String for easier access
                            while (line!= null){
                                    line = reader.readLine();
                                    z += 1;
                            }
                            reader.close();
                            file.close();

                            FileReader file2 = new FileReader(inputR);
                            BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader(file2);
                            String line2 = reader2.readLine();


                            lines = new String[z];

                            int j = 0;

                            while(line2 != null)
                                            {
                                                    line2 = line2.trim();

                                                    lines[j] = line2;
                                                    line2 = reader2.readLine();
                                                    j += 1;
                                            }


                            reader2.close();
                            file2.close();

                    return lines;
            }

            /**
             * Removes all the comments from the Array containing strings
             * @param lines contains strings made of input file
             * @return Array with removed strings
             */
            public static String[] removeComments(String[] lines){


                    for (int i=0; i <lines.length;i++){
                            if (lines[i].startsWith("//"))
                            {
                                    lines[i]="";
                            }
                    }
                    return lines;

            }


            /**
             * This method scans the entire code for name of the classes and methods
             * along with their parameters and stores them in an Array for further use
             * @param lines
             * @return lines array without changing any content
             */
            public static String[] classNames(String[] lines)
            {

                    int total = 0;
                    String[] matches = new String[] {"public ", "class ","private "};

                    for(int b = 0; b <lines.length;b++)
                    {
                            Matcher num = Pattern.compile("\\S+\\s*\\(([^)]*)\\)").matcher(lines[b]);
                            for (int n = 0; n < 3 ;n++)
                            {
                                    if (lines[b].contains(matches[n]))
                                    {
                                            while(num.find())
                                            {
                                                    total += 1;
                                            }
                                    }
                            }
                    }
                    classnames = new String[total];

                    for(int z = 0; z<lines.length;z++)
                    {
                            Matcher mzz = Pattern.compile("\\w+\\s*\\{").matcher(lines[z]);
                            for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
                            {
                              if (lines[z].contains(matches[k])&& !(lines[z].contains("throws "))) //&& !(lines[z].contains("throws "))
                              {                            
                                              while(mzz.find())
                                              {            
                                                     classn.append( mzz.group()+"break");
                                              }
                              }
                            }

                    }

                    for(int z = 0; z <lines.length;z++)
                    {
                            //This matcher with Regex looks for class/method names along with any parameters inside
                            Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\S+\\s*\\(([^)]*)\\)").matcher(lines[z]);
                            int i = 0;
                            for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
                            {
                              if (lines[z].contains(matches[k]) )
                              {                            
                                              while(m.find())
                                              {    
                                                     classn.append( m.group()+"break");
                                                    continue;

                                              }

                                    }

                            }
                    }

                    classnam = classn.toString();
                    classnames = classnam.split("break");
                    /*for(int step = 0; step<classnames.length;step++)
                    {
                            System.out.println(classnames[step]);
                    }*/
                    return lines;
            }




            /**
             * This method removes all the code from the Array and leaves on the
             * Doc comments intact.
             * @param lines
             * @return lines array with only comments remaining ( code is removed )
             */

            public static String[] removeCode(String[] lines)
            {
                    int rep = 0;
                    while ( rep <lines.length){
                lines[rep] = lines[rep].replaceAll("\\*", "Z");
                            if(!(lines[rep].startsWith("Z") || (lines[rep].startsWith("/")))){
                                    lines[rep]="";
                            }
                            lines[rep] = lines[rep].replaceAll("Z", "\\*");
                            rep += 1;
                    }



                    for(int num = 0; num <lines.length; num++)
                    {
                            if(lines[num].isEmpty()){
                                    lines[num] = null;
                            }
                    }

                    return lines;
            }



            /**
             * This method removes the remaining stars, slashes and properly formats each comment
             * before printing it.
             * @param lines The array contains parsed Java Doc comments
             * @return
             * @throws Exception
             */
            public static String[] writeTo(String[] lines) throws Exception
            {
                    BufferedWriter outputWriter = null;
                    outputWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputR));
                    StringBuilder writeTo = new StringBuilder();
                    writeTo.append("<html>\n<body>\n<h2><mark> JAVA DOC COMMENTS</mark> </h2>\n<pre>\n"
                                                                    +"<big><b>Source File:</b> </big>" +"<big>"+ fileName+"</big>" + "\n\n");

                    for(int step = 0; step<lines.length;step++)
                    {
                            if(!(lines[step] == null))
                            {
                            lines[step] = lines[step].replace("@author", "<b>Author: </b>\n&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp");      
                            lines[step] = lines[step].replace("@since", "<b>Since: </b>\n&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp");
                            lines[step] = lines[step].replace("@version", "<b>Version: </b>\n&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp");
                            lines[step] = lines[step].replace("@param", "<b>Parameter: </b>\n&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp");
                            lines[step] = lines[step].replace("@return", "<b>Return: </b>\n&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp");
                            //lines[step] = lines[step].replace("*", "");
                            }
                    }




                    outputWriter.write(writeTo.toString());

                    //write to HTML
                    int countz = 0;
                    int comcount = 0;

                    //classnames[]
                    for(int resum = 0; resum<lines.length;resum++)
                    {

                            if(lines[resum] != null)
                            {
                                    if( lines[resum].charAt(0) == '*' )
                                    {
                                            lines[resum] = lines[resum].replace("*","");
                                    }


                            }
                    }
                    for(int i = 0; i < classnames.length; i++)
                    {
                            System.out.println(classnames[i]);
                    }

                    for(int resum = 0; resum<lines.length;resum++)
                    {
                            if(lines[resum] != null)
                            {

                                    if( lines[resum].charAt(0) == '/' )
                                    {
                                            if(lines[resum].endsWith("*"))
                                            {
                                            lines[resum] = lines[resum].replace("/**","<b>"+classnames[countz]+"</b>");
                                            countz++;
                                            }
                                    }

                                    if( lines[resum].charAt(0) == '/' )
                                    {

                                            lines[resum] = lines[resum].replace("/","\n");

                                    }      
                            }
                    }

                    /*for(int resum = 0; resum<lines.length;resum++)
                    {

                    }*/






                    for(int f = 0; f<lines.length;f++)
                    {
                            if(lines[f] != null)
                            {

                                    /*if(lines[f].startsWith("//") && lines[f].length() == 2)
                                    {
                                            lines[f] = "TEEEST";
                                            countz++;
                                    }*/



                                    outputWriter.write(lines[f]+"\n");

                            }

                    }






                    outputWriter.close();
                    return null;
            }


    }
```

### Console:

```
Please enter path to input file (ex: C:/Program Files/Code.java : 
I:\ICS4U0\DocParse\src\java_doc_parse\ParseDoc.java
Please enter path to html output file (ex: C:/Program Files/Output.html : 
I:\ICS4U0\DocParse\src\java_doc_parse\ParseDochh.html
ParseDoc {
scanread()
removeComments(String[] lines)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
    at java_doc_parse.ParseDoc.writeTo(ParseDoc.java:285)
    at java_doc_parse.Execute.main(Execute.java:14)
classNames(String[] lines)
removeCode(String[] lines)
writeTo(String[] lines)
```

---

I am not sure what is causing this error. Is there a way to fix it or should i just give up on adding class names to comments altogether?

Sorry if i am lacking some information, but i am quite confused myself.

Comment: Can `lines[resum]` resolve to empty string? this might produces the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems to be because you call charAt(0) on what appears to be an empty string.

You already have a null check above, I don't know if it's valid (can your lines ever be null?), but I would change that to a length check, possibly combined with the existing null check.

`if (lines[resum] != null && lines[resum].length > 0) {`

Comment: Holy mother of Moses! The code runs perfectly now! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is where your error resides:

```
 for(int resum = 0; resum<lines.length;resum++)
            {
                    if(lines[resum] != null)
                    {

                            if( lines[resum].charAt(0) == '/' )
                            {
                                    if(lines[resum].endsWith("*"))
                                    {
                                    lines[resum] = lines[resum].replace("/**","<b>"+classnames[countz]+"</b>");
                                    countz++;
                                    }
                            }

                            if( lines[resum].charAt(0) == '/' )
                            {

                                    lines[resum] = lines[resum].replace("/","\n");

                            }      
                    }
            }
```

Try this instead, move the `null` check before entering the for loop:

```
 if(lines[0] != null)
 {
 for(int resum = 0; resum<lines.length;resum++)
            {


                            if( lines[resum].charAt(0) == '/' )
                            {
                                    if(lines[resum].endsWith("*"))
                                    {
                                    lines[resum] = lines[resum].replace("/**","<b>"+classnames[countz]+"</b>");
                                    countz++;
                                    }
                            }

                            if( lines[resum].charAt(0) == '/' )
                            {

                                    lines[resum] = lines[resum].replace("/","\n");

                            }      
                    }
            }
```

Comment: Not only does this not solve the problem, it wouldn't even compile. You have moved the null check outside of the for loop, where the "resum" variable isn't even defined. Even if it were defined, by moving the check outside of the loop you would no longer check every element. This code makes no sense.

Comment: Never heard of an array having null somewhere other than in index 0/the last element. If it does then that's bad code in itself.

Comment: An array can have a null element anywhere. I don't see why it would be more frequent in the first or last element. It all depends on the code that inserts elements of course. It doesn't make sense to generalize and say that elements are usually not null in the middle of an array.

Comment: However, we have not seen the code that fills the `lines` array with elements so we have no way of knowing if elements can indeed be null, but anyway, elements being null isn't even the problem here. The problem was that elements could be *empty strings*. An empty string is a string of length 0, which is very different from null.

Comment: It is normal for strings and arrays to be null terminated. Having null somewhere else could cause problems when other code/functions are used. Especially if it's a collaborative project. Not to say you couldn't, I just personally wouldn't, and I think a lot of programmers would agree. Nonetheless, you are correct about empty strings and null, and I'm glad you solved his problem. I prematurely answered and jumped to conclusions.

Comment: "It is normal for strings and arrays to be null terminated." - null termination when it comes to strings is something entirely different, it's the way to indicate the end of an string with a NUL character (0x00), used e.g. when strings are represented as arrays of characters in C/C++. That is not the same thing as a String object reference being null. And Java arrays are never null terminated. Of course, having null elements in an array could cause problems, and could probably be said to be a bad idea, I agree. That does however not mean that it doesn't happen.
Anyway, we are going OT here.